# Spring Boot: Publish Thymeleaf template without restarting the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there a way to publish Thymeleaf template without running and building the war file?

 This is how my gradle file looks:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'bootBlog'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in production or dev environment? I don't think the solution will be in gradle.

Comment: Will be doing in dev environment. Looking for a gradle specific solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way thymeleaf works is by caching all thymeleaf templates as the server is booting up. This is the reason you are not getting the latest template. To stop the caching, there is an application setting that is in the application.properties called:

```
 spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Turning this off prevents caching and allows the templates to be refreshed without restarting the server.

Once you entered in the configuration, stop the server and start it with `gradle bootRun`. From now on you will be able to get the latest thymeleaf templates without a refresh.

Comment: Does that mean I need to create an application.properties file and set this value?

Comment: Yes. The application.properties needs to be at root of the jar

Comment: This isn't working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655114/spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-how-to-disable-caching-enable-dynamic-reloading

Comment: This saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use Springboot rather than Gradle, you can add two more properties in your properties file :

- project.base-dir (it is not a springboot known property, see it as a
  variable to define the path to your project)
- spring.thymeleaf.prefix

To summerize, your properties file should contain these properties :

- project.base-dir=file:///path/to/your/project/base/dir
- spring.thymeleaf.prefix=${project.base-dir}/src/main/resources/templates/
- spring.thymeleaf.cache=false