# How do I enable Thymeleaf Live Reloading in Spring Boot 1.3

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've created a Spring Boot Gradle project that uses Thymeleaf. My IDE is IntelliJ. I've created an application.properties in the root folder with:

```
spring.resources.cache-period=0
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

But somehow it's still not auto-reloading. I have to hit the "Make Project" button first. I have another project, with the same configuration (not sure about the IntelliJ settings) that strangely enough, does work on refresh.

My application.properties is being read as I can pull a custom property out using the @Value annotation.

For reference, my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'earthalive'
    version = ""
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.22')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Spring Boot 1.3 release documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes):

> The Spring Boot Gradle plugin no longer adds `src/main/resources`
>   directly to the classpath when using bootRun. If you want live,
>   in-place editing we recommend using Devtools. The addResources
>   property can be set in your gradle build if you want to restore Spring
>   Boot 1.2. behaviour.

Thymeleaf relies on `src/main/resources` being added to the classpath **regardless** if you're using spring-boot-devtools or not. Fortunately, spring-boot-devtools does have an option to turn this on again to restore boot 1.2 behaviour.

Add to your build.gradle:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

```
bootRun {
    addResources = true
}
```

*Personal Opinion: It looks to me like Spring-loaded will eventually be deprecated in favour of spring-boot-devtools. Dynamic hotswapping seems to be a complex affair in Spring, and I think the Spring team has decided to rather work on a fast reload basis as is used by devtools.*

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution for Maven?

Comment: for maven look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 1.3 of Spring boot - perhaps the other project is using the devtools - which auto refreshes springBoot apps:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
```

spring-boot-devtools is what makes working with Thymeleaf great for me - in conjunction with Live Reload chrome/firefox extension you won't even have to refresh your browser either.  [Spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.22')
}
```

Comment: I'm not using spring-boot-devtools on either project. Reluctant to add another dependency if I don't require it.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will automatically compile the project upon save. IntelliJ does not. The compile action is what triggers the reload. Which, as an IntelliJ user I find annoying.

I did a review of the devtools and reloading on my blog here: https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-developer-tools/

Comment: I have 2 projects, one that works and one that doesn't. In the project that works, it seems it isn't compiling. It should be loading the templates from the source (not a jar), on-the-fly, so a save-and-refresh works perfectly well. I have no idea though why it's not working for my second project. Perhaps I should create a new project and re-import the code.